# How can you import a Pods Framework in WidgetKit?

Tags: aws-amplify, widgetkit

I am using Amplify, which I installed through cocoapods and it works fine in my "regular" iOS application in Swift.
I have now created a Widget Extension, inside of which I would also like to use Amplify.
I have tried adding Widget.swift to the main app's target, but that didn't let me compile because now there were two @main structs. (For the app & for the widget)
Is there a way to import Amplify and use it in WidgetKit?

Answer (score 3):

Edit your Podfile to apply Pod for all targets: application & widget. Ex:

```
def workspace_pods
  pod 'YourPod'
end

target 'YourApplication' do
  use_frameworks!
  workspace_pods
end

target 'YourWidget' do
  use_frameworks!
  workspace_pods
end
```